# How to sort set of data.frame objects in the list by increasing order?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have set of data.frame object in the list. I want to sort these by increasing order. However, I have simulated data that 5 data.frame objects in the list, How can I sort them? Does anyone know any useful trick of doing this in R? Thanks in advance

## set of data.frame object

```
df1 <- CO2[1:10,]
df2 <- airquality[1:10,]
df3 <- iris[1:10,]
df4 <- cars[1:10,]
df5 <-  attitude[1:10,]

d.list <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
```

## desired output (manually pin out for reference)

```
out_1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)  # original 
out_2 <- list(df2, df1, df3, df4, df5)
out_3 <- list(df3, df1, df2, df4, df5)
out_4 <- list(df4, df1, df2, df3, df5)
out_5 <- list(df5, df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Comment: Explain the rule for reordering. Your example with three is not clear, much less this extension you have in mind for 10-100.

Comment: give me some moment to update with clear example. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[` to reorder (and subset) lists:

```
test_1 <- df.list[c(1, 2, 3)]
test_2 <- df.list[c(2, 1, 3)]
test_3 <- df.list[c(3, 1, 2)]
```

will return your desired outputs.

```
test_1.1 <- df.list[c(1, 2)]
```

will return a list with the first two list elements and

```
test_1.1 <- df.list[c(2, 1)]
```

will return the first two list elements with the order reversed.

For longer lists, you can perform a reordering using `seq_len` and `[`:

```
test_1 <- df.list[seq_len(length(df.list))]
test_2 <- df.list[c(2, seq_len(length(df.list))[-2])]
test_3 <- df.list[c(3, seq_len(length(df.list))[-3])]
```

To randomly rsort the list, you can use `sample`:

```
test_rand <- df.list[sample(seq_len(length(df.list)), length(df.list))]
```

Comment: what if df.list more than three data.frame objects (for example, 10 to 100) in it? In this situation, Is your approach still feasible to apply ?

Comment: You have not motivated the need to reorder the list and I have not seen a pattern from what you provided. I'll add a couple of methods for longer lists.

Answer (score 2):

One option is create a `vector` of `names` (or if the OP intended 'd1', 'd2', 'd3' as `names` of 'df.list' - `v1 <- names(df.list)`).  Then loop through the sequence of 'v1', remove that element from 'v1' (`v1[-i]`), concatenate the 'v1' that corresponds to the sequence (`v1[i]`) and subset the 'df.list'.

```
v1 <- paste0("d", 1:3)
lst <- lapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) df.list[c(v1[i], v1[-i])])
names(lst[[1]])
#[1] "d1" "d2" "d3"
names(lst[[2]])
#[1] "d2" "d1" "d3"
names(lst[[3]])
#[1] "d3" "d1" "d2"
```

#### Update

For the update in the OP's post

```
v2 <- seq_along(d.list)
lst2 <- lapply(v2, function(i) d.list[c(i, setdiff(v2, i))])
identical(lst2[[1]], out_1)
#[1] TRUE
identical(lst2[[2]], out_2)
#[1] TRUE
identical(lst2[[3]], out_3)
#[1] TRUE

identical(lst2[[4]], out_4)
#[1] TRUE
identical(lst2[[5]], out_5)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
names(df.list) <- v1
```

Comment: @user88911 If you check your `df.list`, the 'd1', 'd2', 'd3' are not actually found.  It is better to name the df.list with the object names.  You may have to use `list(d1 = data.frame(..`

Comment: I did typo, now I updated my post, d1,d2, d3 are exist and they are list element of df.list.

Comment: @user88911  If those are `names`, then my solution should work.

Comment: Yes, I agreed your solution, it was well motivated. Unfortunately, my simulated data and desired output confused readers, I apologize for this. FYI, I updated all the text and toy data with clear goal. Thx

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, appreciated.